# Is $E[X] = E[X|Y=E[Y]]$?

Tags: probability

In other words, assuming the random variables are not independent, is the unconditional expectation equal to the conditional expectation such that the other variable is at its expected value?

Comment: Can the relationship be curvilinear (eg, E[X|Y] = f(Y) = Y^2)?

Comment: There is no restriction on it, it may be linear, it may be anything else.

Comment: I suspect it's true if the relationship is rectilinear, but it's clearly not true for my example above.

Comment: I do not see why is it not true for your example, we know nothing about $E[Y]$ in this case.

Comment: Since the chance that $Y=E[Y]$ may be zero, how do you even define the right hand side?  For instance, suppose $Y$ is a Bernoulli variate with parameter $p$, $0 \lt p \lt 1$. Since $Y$ can take on only the values $0$ and $1$ but has expectation $p$, just what would $E[X|Y=p]$ mean?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workup of @CrockGill's example (coded in `R`):

```r
set.seed(3423)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
Y = runif(500, min=-2, max=2)
X = Y^2 + rnorm(500, mean=0, sd=.5)
plot(Y, X)
lines(seq(-2,2,by=.1), seq(-2,2,by=.1)^2, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly not true. If $Y = X^2$ and $X$ has mean zero, then $E(Y | X = E(X)) = 0$ but $E(Y) > 0$.

Comment: This is a lovely example and I thank you for your effort. It seems that I have not posed the question correctly, let me rephrase it. $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed, one is not a transformation of the other, they are simply jointly distributed (and not independent of one another). In this case, is $E[X] = E[X|Y=E[Y]]$?

Comment: Two variables being jointly distributed does not preclude the possibility that one is a function of the other. In this example, if you add mean zero error,  $\epsilon$, so that $Y = X^2 + \epsilon$ then $X$ and $Y$ have a non-degenerate joint distribution but the counterexample still holds.

Comment: Thank you ! Then I fail to understand what $E[X]$ means, what is unconditional expectation, we do not know anything about the other variable, yet we do not assume it is at its expected value !

Comment: $Z = E(X|Y)$ is a random variable because $Y$ is a random variable. It's true that $E(Z) = E(X)$, which is the law of total probability, but it does not imply that $E(X) = E(X|Y=E(Y))$.

Comment: How do we know that $E(Y) = 1$? Must we not know something about the distribution of $X$ to determine $E(Y)$?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, you are correct. I originally wrote that X was standard normal and erroneously edited it. Now the answer, as written, is correct.